# Socket programming with Multiple ServerSockets

Tags: java, sockets

I want to implement a socket application that will allow two clients to communicate. Right now i have implemented it for single server and multiple clients through TCP protocol. Now what i need is, i want to implement a class that will monitor the server, And if the number of clients exceeds the limit then start new server and incoming client request will redirected to that server.

If any one have any idea of how to achieve this please let me know.

Comment: What about doing this at the network level, with the help of a tool like HAProxy maybe, which will bring you extra benefits in the same time?

Comment: Yes! that may be a good help if wanted to achieve that anyhow. But here as it is an academic project i am expected to do in such a way that the logic to handle and balance load should be implemented in project.